# Formatting issue with IE6 working well with IE 6+

Tags: css, formatting, internet-explorer-6, haslayout

I have my site working perfectly in IE 6+ but it looks weird in IE 6 or IE 5.5, as I can't ignore the users with IE6 because still around 6% of traffic occur from this version. I am looking forward to have the alternate.

With my some research I came to know that by setting haslayout property, I can solve out formatting issue, but I consider myself extremely poor in CSS and hence I need a help of yours to rectify this issue.

You can find the URL below& you can see it's behavior in IE6, just in case if you are unable to test you can check it by viewing the source, please share your suggestions.

URL: http://anujtripathi.net/BlogListing.aspx?Id=2

Comment: Warning. My antivirus says that this site contains threat

Comment: That's strange, could you please let me know what kind of threat it is telling. I am not using any active x control, it's simple asp.net controls and widget from twitter [I can't blame them], and one visitor info widget. & that's it. I am surprise to know why this has happened and curious at the same time to know the reason.
:O

Comment: Hey, just help me in this.. if my system has any virus , can it effect the application that I have developed in asp.net. Please let me know. it's a very crucial issue that you have found out & I want to rectify i ASAP because I & my users have been never encountered with this issue. Even I opened my site from my company which is using Maccafe [which used to be updated weekly] & I have never recieved any message. Please let me know the name of your antivirus.

Comment: Object: `http://anujtripathi.net/rionded_corners.inc.js`; Infection: `JS:Illredir-CB [Trj]`. Same with /js/jquery-1.2.3.min.js. My antivirus: Avast 5.0.507.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be error with the rounded corner Js file and jquery-1.2.3.min.js, but I don't know why it is showing infected sign as I have gathered them from " http://jquery.com/ ". Any guess or idea why this has happened ?

Comment: This link may help, once you figure out the correct CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863136/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-ie-compatibility-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (default.css):

```
.bg1 {
    padding: 0 7px 20px 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/img4.gif) repeat-x;
        width: 95%; 
}
```

Try shrinking down 95% to like around 92%.

You can use a IE6 hack like so:

```
.bg1 {
  padding: 0 7px 20px 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  background: #FFFFFF url(images/img4.gif) repeat-x;
  width: 95%;
}

* html .bg1 {
  width: 92%; /* Star Html Hack IE6 only */
}

*+html .bg1 {
  width: 93%; /* Star Html Hack IE7 only */
}
```

But I highly recommend learning the right way and looking at the link below for organizing CSS for cross browser compatibility:
[What is the best way to deal with IE compatibility issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863136/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-ie-compatibility-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your border widths, margins and paddings. It looks like your content is being pushed down because there isn't enough horizontal space. For a quick check, make your main container a little longer and see if the content shifts up.